# Cron trigger issue with Quartz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Can anyone tell me if a Cron expression of 1 0 * * * ? will mean that a Quartz job in Java runs at one second past the hour, every hour?

I always seem to get these wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, one second past the hour, every hour, but you're missing a `*`.**

The parameters for a cron line in quartz are:

- seconds of hour (0-59)
- minute of hour (0-59)
- hour of day (0-23)
- day of month (1-31)
- month of year (1-12)
- day of week (1-7, 7 is Saturday)
- (optional) year

So you would need six or seven values:

```
1 0 * * * *
```

Comment: So what would it be for one second after every hour? Thanks.

Comment: In what way did you confuse it? Should it be 1 0 * * * *
or something else?

Comment: Minor mistake: it's the seconds of the minute ;)

Comment: I've just tested 1 0 * * * * and it didn't fire at 1 second past the hour. What should the expression be?

Comment: You're scheduling this in Quartz or in `crontab`?  In crontab, there are only five parameters, and there is no seconds at the beginning.

Comment: The expression in @Erick Robertson's answer is correct. If it is not firing then you have probably not set the trigger on the job you wish to execute correctly

Comment: Does anyone know why Java (or Quartz) uses the wrong range for day of week? (In cron, 0-6 is Sunday to Saturday; 7 is also Sunday). So much damage…

Comment: I believe this is Quartz, and the answer is "because sometimes third party libraries suck like that."